# How to load XML at compile time

Tags: c++, xml

The goal is to use an external library which creates an object by parsing an XML file. This works fine with a real XML file in a specified folder, but I don't want to deliver a XML with the compiled Software. So my idea was to load the xml once while compiling and then use it to create the objects.

The provided functions the library has are the following two:

```
create(const std::string &xmlPathName, const std::string &variantName)
create(std::istream &xml, const std::string &variantName)
```

The question is now how I can load and store an XML file while compiling and the call one of this two functions on runtime.

Is it possible to load the XML on compile time and store it as std::istream? 
Or has anyone a better suggestion to solve this.

Using Windows environment and VC++ 2010 compiler.

Comment: That's all very nice.  Stackoverflow is a question & answer site.  Are you here looking for an answer to something?  If so, what's the question?

Comment: By definition, a function has to be called at runtime, not at compile time.  Unless the functions are declared as `constexpr`.

Comment: If you just want to embed the XML with your application, then include it as a resource. The mechanism for doing so is platform dependent.

Comment: It's also fine to just include the whole XML file into the dll. But it should be only one file in the end. I'm using Windows as platform and VC++10 compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solution to be platform independent I created a Header file wich contains the whole xml as a String and pass this as istringstream to the create function.

```
// xmlfile.h

static inline std::string BuildXmlFile ()
{
    std::string xml;
    xml = "<\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\?>\n";
    xml += "<Device xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n";
    .
    .
    .
    xml += "</Device>";
    return xml;
}

std::istringstream xml_file(BuildXmlFile());
```